# insertBefore adding objects to xml the wrong way

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Basically, when I'm trying to add multiple items from an RSS feed to an XML file using php, the insertBefore class adds the newest items the wrong way (ie, I want it to add them at the top of the file, from oldest to newest, but instead it adds them newest to oldest) How can I fix this? (Sorry for the terrible wording) Here's my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


$dom->load(myfile);

$channel = $dom->getElementsByTagName('channel');

foreach ($channel as $channels) {

$item1 = $dom->createElement('item');
$item2 = $dom->createElement('item');
$item3 = $dom->createElement('item');

$title1 = $dom->createElement('title', $t1);
$title2 = $dom->createElement('title', $t2);
$title3 = $dom->createElement('title', $t3);

$content1 = $dom->createElement('media:content'); 
$conatt1 = $dom->createAttribute('url');

$content2 = $dom->createElement('media:content'); 
$conatt2 = $dom->createAttribute('url');

$content3 = $dom->createElement('media:content'); 
$conatt3 = $dom->createAttribute('url');

$conatt1->value = $u1;
$conatt2->value = $u2;
$conatt3->value = $u3;

$channels->insertBefore($item1, $channels->firstChild);  
$channels->insertBefore($item2, $channels->firstChild);  
$channels->insertBefore($item3, $channels->firstChild);  

$item1->appendChild($title1); 
$item2->appendChild($title2); 
$item3->appendChild($title3); 

$item1->appendChild($content1); 
$item2->appendChild($content2); 
$item3->appendChild($content3); 

$content1->appendChild($conatt1);
$content2->appendChild($conatt2);
$content3->appendChild($conatt3);

}
```

and the XML it makes=

```
<channel>
 <item>
  <title>item3</title>
  <media:content url="url3"/>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>item2</title>
  <media:content url="url2"/>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>item1</title>
  <media:content url="url"/>
 </item>

//rest of the RSS 
</channel>
```

But I want it so it adds the items like this:

```
<channel>
 <item>
  <title>item1</title>
  <media:content url="url1"/>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>item2</title>
  <media:content url="url2"/>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>item3</title>
  <media:content url="url3"/>
 </item>

//rest of the RSS 
</channel>
```

Any advice (again, sorry for the terrible explanation)

### edit

Here is my other code, how would I do the same with this?

```
$fom = new DOMDocument;
$fom->formatOutput = true;
$fom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$fom->load("file");
$channel = $fom->getElementsByTagName('channel');

foreach ($channel as $channels) {

$item1 = $fom->createElement('item');
$title1 = $fom->createElement('title', $titles[$i]);

$content1 = $fom->createElement('media:content'); 
$conatt1 = $fom->createAttribute('url');

$conatt1->value = $links[$i];

$channels->insertBefore($item1, $channels->firstChild);
$item1->appendChild($title1); 
$item1->appendChild($content1);  
$content1->appendChild($conatt1);

$fom->formatOutput = true;
$fom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$fom->save("file");
}
}
```

Comment: Just change the order. insert the last (url3) first, and the first (url1) at last. That should already solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you do

```
$channels->insertBefore($item1, $channels->firstChild);
```

after this call, `$item1` has become the first child of `$channels`.  Therefore when on the next line you do

```
$channels->insertBefore($item2, $channels->firstChild);
```

it inserts `$item2` before `$item1`.

Instead, you should cache the first value returned by `$channels->firstChild` in a variable, and then `insertBefore` that:

```
$insertPoint = $channels->firstChild;
$channels->insertBefore($item1, $insertPoint);
$channels->insertBefore($item2, $insertPoint);
$channels->insertBefore($item3, $insertPoint);
```

Now `$insertPoint` is always the element that was the first child of `$channels` before you started inserting new items.

Comment: Cool, this worked, but I have code on another page which uses foreach instead of the three separate items (I've made an edit above) how would I do the same thing with this?

Comment: @looserlf in your second example you only appear to be doing one `insertBefore` so that shouldn't need any changes.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make that clear, the whole thing is in a for tag, which takes titles and urls from arrays, didn't include this, because I didn't think it was relevant.